# unable to find data in sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Here's what I have done.

```
  public void addToFavorites2(View view) {


        //ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        //button.setImageResource(R.mipmap.star_clicked_button);

        int movieId = favoriteMovieId;


SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("FavoritesIdKey", MODE_PRIVATE);

        Log.v("tessssst", String.valueOf(settings.contains(favoriteMovieTitle)));
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

        editor.putString(favoriteMovieTitle, String.valueOf(movieId));

        editor.commit();

    }
    public boolean movieIsInFavorites()
    {

        Log.v("method check","is working");


SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("FavoritesIdKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Log.v("tezzzzzt", String.valueOf(settings.contains(favoriteMovieTitle)));

        if(settings.contains(String.valueOf(favoriteMovieId)))
        {
            Log.v("truth test","true");
            return true;
        }
        Log.v("truth test","false");
        return false;

    }
```

In the given code I have created two methods. in the first method when I call

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("FavoritesIdKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
settings.contains(FavoriteMovieTitle);
```

the data is found and returns true. 
when I call the same

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("FavoritesIdKey", MODE_PRIVATE);
settings.contains(FavoriteMovieTitle);
```

In the second method, it does not return true. is there a fundamental thing about shared preferences that I am missing? if more information is needed i apologize. both methods are next to each other without anything between them.

edit- I will add that the first method is called when i press a button on the details screen(details screen is already finished setup and showing).
the second method i was calling in the onCreateView attempting to check if the movie is already in the favorites list apon start up.

Comment: but in second method you are checking  movieId `settings.contains(String.valueOf(favoriteMovieId))`

Comment: Exactly what @skadoosh said.

Comment: holy crap. im tired. thanks.

Comment: i corrected it, it is still behaving the same wrong way

Comment: i sorry i figured it out... i was trying to call the second method in oncreateview before favoriteMovieTitle was assigned in the oncreateview method.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is called when you press a button and the second method is called in the onCreateView. So the second method is called before the first method. However, you insert favoriteMovieTitle into xml in the first method so when the second method was called, favoriteMovieTitle had not been in xml and it would return false.

Comment: im not sure what you mean by "had not been in the xml". i know the first method is what adds the data to sharedpreferences but im looking for data that is already in sharedpreferances before the app is restarted. on another note... when does an imagebutton get created when it only exists in xml? if i try to assign an object to findviewbyid, the imagebutton is still null if i try to look for it in oncreateview

Answer (score -1):

To **Store/Obtain** shared preferences, use the following method In your activity

```
SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("FavoritesIdKey", 
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**To store** value in **`SharedPreferences`**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(favoriteMovieTitle, String.valueOf(movieId));
```

**To read** **`SharedPreferences`** in other class write this line if same class 
then no need to write this direct use `getString`

```
SharedPreferences settings = this.getSharedPreferences("FavoritesIdKey",
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

If your are in same class the above line not need to write again.

```
String myvalueInPref = settings.getString(favoriteMovieTitle, "defaultValue");
```